# cocos2dx CCArray of sprites

Tags: cocos2d-x

I am working on **cocos2dx**. I am fetching images from facebook for the Leaderboard.
When images fetched from facebook I used them as CCtexture but I have lot of images so, each time I don't want to create object of CCTexture.

I used CCArray but it also create each object of CCTexture.

```
    CCArray* ccArray = new CCArray();

        CCObject* ccText = NULL;
        CCTexture2D *ccTexture = dynamic_cast<CCTexture2D*>(ccText);
        CCTexture2D * ccTexture0 = new  CCTexture2D();
        CCTexture2D * ccTexture1 = new  CCTexture2D();

        CCARRAY_FOREACH(ccArray, ccText)
        {

            ccTexture=new CCTexture2D();
                ccArray->addObject(ccTexture);
                ccArray->addObject(ccTexture0);
                ccArray->addObject(ccTexture1);


        }
```

Comment: how do you use the images and what would you like to do instead of creating textures? And what is the main problem here, the time it takes to create a texture or the memory usage of the textures?

Comment: this is not the correct way to use CCArray. Tell me where the texture is available.

Comment: Actually, i am using texture for making sprites. So, do i have to create object of textures again and again.@Jain I think  you guys are making MMO how you implement so much textures